# Does the SonarQube GitHub plugin work on version 4.3.2?

Tags: github, sonarqube

I'm just trying to verify whether or not version 1.1 of the GitHub plugin will work on SonarQube v 4.3.2?

On the plugin page (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) I see that 1.3 is for 5.6+ and 1.2 for 4.5.2-5.5 but the others don't list supported SonarQube versions.

Answer (score 2):

I do confirm that neither the 1.2 or 1.3 versions are compatible with SonarQube 4.3.2. The [compatibility matrix](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix) available on the SonarQube Github plugin page is correct.

Comment: So is 1.1 compatible? I don't see a compatibility matrix...am I just blind?